# Como receber cabeçalhos vindos da cURL?

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou fazendo uma requisição via **cURL** da seguinte forma (é apenas teste, não está em produção)

```
<?php

$post = [
    "Primeiro",
    "Segundo"
];

$headers = [
    'Terceiro',
    'Quarto'
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, __DIR__ . '/er.php?teste');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);  //Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

E estou tentando receber os **dados** E O **CABEÇALHO** da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

if ( isset($_GET["teste"]) ) {

    print_R ( $_SERVER["headers"] );
    print_R ( $_POST );

}
?>
```

Os **$_POST** recebo normalmente. Mas não estou sabendo como receber as **headers**.

Pesquisei  a saída `print_R ( $_SERVER );` e a key **headers** não existe.

O que eu devo fazer para receber o **cabeçalho** enviado pela **cURL**?

**EDIT**:

tentei também da forma abaixo e não recebi o cabeçalho:

```
$headers = [
    'X-Apple-Tz: 0',
    'X-Apple-Store-Front: 143444,12',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Cache-Control: no-cache',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
    'Host: www.example.com',
    'Referer: http://www.example.com/index.php', //Your referrer address
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0',
    'X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true'
];
```

Comment: O *array* de cabeçalhos deve ser um *array* associativo, em que a chave é o nome do cabeçalho. Da forma que fez não faz sentido. Corrigindo isso, veja se receberá o valor em `$_SERVER["HTTP_<nome>"]`

Comment: Ok. Pode me explicar como fazer?

Comment: Sabe o que são os cabeçalhos HTTP? Sabe criar um array associativo?

Comment: veja ao final da pergunta por favor. Editei!

Comment: desculpa, sei sim. Mas queria reduzir a quantidade de texto na pergunta e acabei me atrapalhando

Comment: Acredito que isso possa te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9183272/3687410 dá uma olhada.

Comment: Coloque o `print_r($_SERVER)` também

Comment: Sim, mas como print_r($_SERVER) vai ajudar? se não tem neuma  $_SERVER co  indice sendo índice do array enviado? Fiquei na dúvida!

Comment: E com o nome `HTTP_<nome>`, como citei no primeiro comentário?

Comment: tipo assim? print_r ( $_SERVER["HTTP_X-Apple-Tz"] );

Comment: Chegou a ver o link que enviei mais acima?

Comment: Lí sim e fi alguns testes, mas o que eu preciso não sai nas variáveis!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar um requisição no cURL usando os headers você precisa usar:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Terceiro: 42',
    'Quarto: 404'
]);
```

Entretanto, os `$headers` devem seguir um padrão de: `Nome: Valor`.

---

Na outra ponta, quando receber a requisição, poderá usar o `$_SERVER` da seguinte forma, afim de acessa-los:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_TERCEIRO']
```

O nome deve sempre começar com `HTTP_` e deve sempre ser maiúsculo, assim como substituir qualquer `-` por `_`.

---

Isso deverá retornar `42`, que é o valor do header `Terceiro`.

Comment: regras...sempre elas. Obrigado!